# How to add part of css property value through scope in ng-style in angular

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I'm trying to add border through ng-style but not able to find out how can I concate value from `scope` variable.

Below all are not working.

```
<div ng-style="{'border-top' :'1px solid' + myClass}">Demo text</div>
<div ng-style="{'border-top' :'1px solid myClass'}">Demo text</div>
<div ng-style="{'border-top' :1px solid myClass}">Demo text</div>
```

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/24132/)

Comment: `<div ng-style="{'border-top' :'1px solid '+myClass}">Demo text</div>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the `space(" ")` in expression.

```js
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.myClass = "red";
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <div ng-style="{'border-top' :'5px solid '+myClass}">Demo text</div>
    <!--====================================^^^ -->
  </div>
</div>
```

### [**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/U3pVM/24133/)

Answer (score 0):

you sould use `ng-class` directive to add class!

```
  <div ng-style="{'border-top' :'1px solid' }" ng-class="myClass">Demo text</div>
```